# Update Array Of Strings to new JSONB column of Array Of Objects in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance

I would like to backfill my data from an array to strings from one column `columns` to another `jsonb` column `ordered_columns`

I'm doing it in rails and I know it works, but I would like to get this behavior with raw SQL

Example how it should work:

```
columns: ["city", "leaseUsers"]

ordered_columns: [{key: "city",visible:true} , {key:"leaseUsers", visible:true}]
```

I know I should update with `jsonb_set` but I'm not sure how I should generate a new array to update the new column.

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest the array, then aggregate it back using `jsonb_agg()` and `jsonb_build_object()`

```
update the_table
   set ordered_columns = (select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('key', item, 'visible', true))
                          from jsonb_array_elements(columns) as c(item));
```